# Laravel emails and queues

Tags: php, email, queue, laravel-5.1

In my app a user can request for some service from the list and app should notify other users that provide this service of a new request.

Since many users can provide the service I'm sending multiple e-mails.

At the moment I'm setting up sending of e-mails through queues and I'm wondering what would be best approach here:

Create a new queue and send message to appropriate users via `->bcc($arrayOfEmails)` or create a new queue for each e-mail as:

```
foreach($arrayOfEmails as $email)
{
  Mail::queue....
  ...
  ->to($email)
  ...
}
```

I'm leaning toward the second solution as it makes more sense to me. I beleive that way I can handle failed e-mails more easily but I've never done this so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a matter of personal preference.

I'd go with separate calls to `Mail::queue` for each email. I think the code will be a little simpler and easier to understand.

Compare:

```
foreach ($email in $list) {

    Mail::queue('emails.my-message', $data, function ($message) use ($email) {
        ...
        $message->to($email);
        ...
    });

}
```

versus

```
Mail::queue('emails.my-message', $data, function ($message) use ($list) {
    ...
    foreach ($email in $list) {
        $message->bcc($email);
    }
    ...
});
```

A minor difference, to be sure, but I think it's easier to understand what you're doing in the first case.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking the same. I'll wait a little longer and if noone answers I'll go with this method.